# what size of the array after Java String.split()?

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, when the string text is "a#b#c", the array after split("#") is ["a","b","c"] and the length is 3;

when the text is "a#", the array turns to be ["a"]. Why did i not get a array of ["a", ""]?

what's the trick of it?

Comment: What trick? It just omitted an empty entry.

Comment: The code is doing what it should really do.

Comment: The 'trick' is exactly what it says in the `[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Read the javadoc of [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): *This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
s.split("#", -1);
```

From the docs on the 2-arg form:

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

That's simply the way the `split` function works. It's in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**